# Execute PHP script on Ajax POST

Tags: php, ajax

I'm making a ajax script which is sending some values to another script. This script has to be executed (with these values) after sending this values. I've tried several things but I have no clue how to do this. Anyone has any idea how to do this?

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'script.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'text',
    data: {result:JSON.stringify(values)},
    success: function(response){ 
        // preform script?
        }//end success

}); //end ajax
```

Comment: This will execute `script.php`. What more do you need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ajax itself can accept json in the data key.
It makes it more readable for you and manageable.

before the ajax call just build the json like this:

```
var data = {value1: value1, value2:value2, ..., valueN=valueN}
```

And then use it with your ajax:

```
$("#buttonID").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'script.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: data,
        success: function(response){ 
            $('body').append(response);
            }//end success

    }); //end ajax 
});
```

And just like that you can read in your php the variables like this:

```
$value1 = $_POST['value1'];
```

Comment: Yes I did those things already, but I want to execute script.php as well if it's succeeded to pass the values.

Comment: That is what ajax do.

It runs the url with those parameters.

Yuor response is the answer from the page.

Comment: `success: function(response){ $(#element).html(response); }`

Comment: That's strange, even when I make a alert in the PHP script it doesn't show at all. The ajax doesn't give an 500 error or anything at all.

Comment: OH I think I see where the problem is.

You might have not binded it to any event?

Comment: I have no clue what you're talking about to be honest, can you show an example?

Comment: First, tell me when do you want this ajax to run?

As soon as you open the page?
When you click a button?

Comment: It's on a button click. (it's an application) the application makes values which will be sended through the ajax to script.php. In this script I will send a POST request to another server via an API.

Comment: Check my edited comment tell me if that's pretty much what you have

Comment: Yes, that's what I have, if I console.log something on the succes then it works. So it sends the values.

Comment: Then you're done.

Ajax already called the page with those values.

Comment: But when I put an echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('test');</script>"; in the script.php it doesn't show at all. It should show then right?

Comment: No.

If you want the actual response to be shown, you will have to show the response somewhere.

Check my additional edit.

Comment: I added $('body').append(response);

Comment: The body append did the job! Thanks!

Comment: Just FYI, It's not "healthy" to append things to the body.

I would recommand make a div with a specific id, and just shove the response content into it.

Answer (score 0):

You want execute another script after executing this?
JS running on the client computer. You can not run php script there. But you can call php from server like this

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'script.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'text',
    data: {result:JSON.stringify(values)},
    success: function(response){ 
        $.ajax({
             url: 'otherscript.php',
             type: 'POST' ... });
        }//end success

}); //end ajax
```

or you can rewrite your code on js. Or you can generate js from php (

> < script src='js.php?some' >

)